# How to move files from subdirectory to a directory using a for loop

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

How do I move a file 1 directory up using loop? Can someone maybe help me out?

I tried this:

```
for dir in */*/
    do mv "$dir"/*
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like that:

```
for dir in */*/
do
    echo mv "$dir"* "${dir%/*/}" # Drop the echo after tested it
done
```

Note that this will move *all files and directories* under `$dir` to the parent directory of the `$dir`. If you want to move a specific file, replace `"$dir"*` with `"$dir"file` where `file` is the filename of the specific file. Also be very careful where and how you use this code after `echo` removed (running in the wrong directory would be catastrophic)